# How to unmarshall this XML file structure

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How would I go about unmarshalling this XML file structure with JAXB:

```
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>
      <property id="generationDate">
        <value>20150525</value>
      </property>
      <property id="hostAddress">
        <value>192.168.0.250</value>
        </property>
    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

Snippet from Java class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

    @XmlRootElement(name = "document")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    class PDFDocument {

        @XmlID
        @XmlAttribute(name = "generationDate")    
        private String generationDate;
```

Snippet from Unmarshalling code:

```
 PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument();
            try {
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PDFDocument.class);
                Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                doc = (PDFDocument) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(filePath));

            } catch (JAXBException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileFunctions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            System.out.println(doc.getGenerationDate());
```

But i'm not sure how to reference each value of a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so basically your Java Object Structure is wrong. You need to analyze the XML and then you need to build the Java Object structure accordingly.

If you look at the XML, you have a Document, and inside the Document you have Properties, inside properties the basic properties and so on.

So similarly you need to have java classes, A Document Class, inside document you need to have properties class, inside that Basic class and so on. I have shown the class structure below, so that you can get an idea.

Document Class -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "document")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class PDFDocument {

@XmlElement(name = "properties")
private DocumentProperty documentProperty;

public DocumentProperty getDocumentProperty() {
    return documentProperty;
}

public void setDocumentProperty(DocumentProperty documentProperty) {
    this.documentProperty = documentProperty;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PDFDocument{" +
            "documentProperty=" + documentProperty + "\n" +
            '}';
}
}
```

Class to Hold Properties -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "properties")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DocumentProperty {

@XmlElement(name = "basic")
private Basic basic;

public Basic getBasic() {
    return basic;
}

public void setBasic(Basic basic) {
    this.basic = basic;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "DocumentProperty{" +
            "basic=" + basic + "\n" +
            '}';
}
}
```

Basic Class -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "basic")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Basic {

@XmlElementRef
private List<Property> propertyList;

public List<Property> getPropertyList() {
    return propertyList;
}

public void setPropertyList(List<Property> propertyList) {
    this.propertyList = propertyList;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Basic{" +
            "propertyList=" + propertyList + "\n" +
            '}';
}
}
```

Property Class -

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "property")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Property {

@XmlAttribute(name = "id")
private String id;

@XmlElement(name = "value")
private String value;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Property{" +
            "id='" + id + "\n" +
            ", value='" + value + "\n" +
            '}';
}
}
```

The Above Class structure works with the XML you provided. But I guess you will have to change this structure since There will be other types of Properties in Document other than Basic Type. In that Case I suggest you to have abstract Document Property class and to extend that to Basic and Other types of Properties.

The Test class -

```
public class XmlTest {

@Test
public void testXml() throws Exception {

    String xml = "<document>" +
            "  <properties>" +
            "    <basic>" +
            "      <property id=\"generationDate\">" +
            "        <value>20150525</value>" +
            "      </property>\n" +
            "      <property id=\"hostAddress\">" +
            "        <value>192.168.0.250</value>" +
            "        </property>" +
            "    </basic>" +
            "  </properties>" +
            "</document>";

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(PDFDocument.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        PDFDocument document = (PDFDocument) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));


        System.out.println("PDF Document Structure -" +document.toString());


        for(Property property : document.getDocumentProperty().getBasic().getPropertyList()) {
            if(property.getId().equals("generationDate")){
                System.out.println("Generation Date : "+property.getValue());
            }
        }
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Running the Test class Produces the Following Result.

```
PDFDocument{
documentProperty=
DocumentProperty{
basic=Basic{
propertyList=[
Property{
id='generationDate
, value='20150525
}, 
Property{id='hostAddress
, value='192.168.0.250
}]
}
}
}
```

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Great, wasn't sure about the class structures so your answer helped. It is now implemented and works like a charm ;-)